# using a single page web application and still utilizing '/login' or '/register'

Tags: express, single-page-application, url-parameters

So I have a single page application but I really want to utilize things like `http://webaddress.com/login` or other `/pages` i have tried something like this

set website "pages" like this

```js
var paths = {
  'me':{
    function(){
      //function that gets userdata and appends the information for them 
      // if the authKey is not defined then i would do window.location = '/login'
    }
  }
}
```

and when the page loads I do `handlePath()` which looks like this

```js
function handlePath(){
  var path = window.location.pathname.substr(1);
  if(path in paths){
    paths[path].function()
  }
}
```

but I feel like this is a super dirty way of doing it is using express and socket.io and whish that there was a way of doing it with one of those libraries. one of the problems that I run into is if the user is not authenticated I want to send them to `/register` or maybe `/login` but doing that gives me a page not found error because in express I only have a route for the index page if I add additional routes it will load the page but goes right back to the start and basically is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Crisp React](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/) is an Express/React boilerplate that allows you to split React application into several SPAs. I'm the author. Out of the box it comes with 2 SPAs called `first` and `second` with Express serving the pages: `/first` and `/second`.

You can have 2 SPAs called  `login` and `app` instead. To achieve that modify a single configuration file. Then build the solution and you get Express running and automatically configured to serve `/login` and `/app`.

Arbitrary number of SPAs is supported so you can additionally have `/reports`, `/dashboards` etc. You provide React components that render these pages. It's all explained in README.

Comment: so i would end up having to convert over to a react app

Comment: oh boy react seems cool and all but sometimes i just don't know i have never fully gotten into it

Comment: No need to get into React. You can partially borrow server-side logic which remains the same: (1) expose few pages e.g. be prepared to serve only few these pages (2) if the handler of this particular page is unhappy about something then redirect. The only difference would be that is this sample  _something_ is a request for React internal page which Express is not aware of, in your case it will be lack of login cookie for `/app` handler which redirects to `/login` or presence of valid login cookie for `/login` handler which redirects to `/app'.